# Rendering a nested model handlebars?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a data structure like this.

```
var myModel {
    _id: 798698,
    username: "John",
    message: {
        message1: "Some cool messsage",
        message2: "I'm mad Ohio State lost"
    }
}
```

The `message` object is a little tricky. Inside my handlebars template.

```
{{#each message}}
    <div class="message">
        {{../username}}: {{this}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Then when that renders the output is something like this.

```
<div class="NCAA">
    <div class="NBA">
        <div class="message">steve: What?</div>
        <div class="message">steve: Okay?</div>
        <div class="message">steve: Hey</div>
    </div>

    <div class="NBA"></div>

    <div class="NBA">
        <div class="message">
            Iowastate: Hey nikeman
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class names come from a backbone view, but the problem is the template is being wrapped by a div and I am not sure how to prevent that so that its just a list of `.message`.. Also I cant identify why there is an empty div, I have suspicions but cant point my finger to it..

Here is the backbone view code, just to show you how things are rendered.

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

var ChatView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    className: 'NBA',
    template: require('../../templates/message.hbs')
});

module.exports = CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    className: 'NCAA',
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
    },
    itemView: ChatView
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Backbone, [every view](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) is associated with an el. At the time of instantiation, if you do not provide an el for the view, backbone uses an empty DIV. I guess this is what is happening in your case.

So at the time of your view instantiation, just provide an el element like this:

```
var myView = new ChartView({ el: $('.myElementForView') })
```

Read this text from [Backbone View el documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

> All views have a DOM element at all times (the el property), whether they've already been inserted into the page or not. In this fashion, views can be rendered at any time, and inserted into the DOM all at once, in order to get high-performance UI rendering with as few reflows and repaints as possible. this.el is created from the view's tagName, className, id and attributes properties, if specified. If not, el is an empty div.

Comment: oh okay thanks I saw this, but I thought because of my data structure it was adding the div.. thanks

Comment: I actually already know this, but take a look at my model structure. I am going to need to open a new question.

Comment: The only way to prevent Backbone from wrapping your view in an `el` is to give it one.  That's what the `el` property of a View is for - http://backbonejs.org/#View-el.  If you specify the `el` property of your View, just make sure that the element exists at the time the View is instantiated.  However, I believe that you will get slightly better performance when you let Backbone create its own `el`, as it will create a detached Node and do all the rendering in advance.  Then it can insert the HTML into the page all at once, minimizing page repaints, etc.

Comment: @TNguyen you are right. This is what I mentioned in my answer. Moreover, you can also do this. `$('someElement').html(myView.render())` over-ride render method to return el's markup from the view

Comment: Yup, you had the correct answer.  I'm just providing more details for Michael.

Comment: @TNguyen Thanks for the explanation. You really simplified the words mentioned in Backbone view el documentation..That's gonna help someone :)